# Css styling for a <form> <label> using "display: block" not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a form label that I want displayed at the top of the form. I've seen that this can be done by setting the CSS display to block but after trying that method I don't see any results. I've confirmed that the CSS file is linked properly because I'm able to adjust other style factors just fine. I'd like to understand the reasoning behind why this is happening. I appreciate the help. Thank you for your time!

```
'''
.reflectionForm label{
    display: block;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: green
}
'''

'''
function Reflection() {
    return (
        <div> Entry Page

        <form class="reflectionForm">
            <label for="newEntryId"> New Entry:
            <textarea type="text" id="newEntryId" name="newEntryName" rows="30" cols="75"/>
            </label>
       
        </form>
        </div>
    );
}
'''
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4TL1.jpg)

Comment: is there any css or react code you did not post? I tested it on a sandbox and it works just as expected https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-brown-97odn1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to target **only the text**, not the whole label with the textarea inside.

You can solve this by putting the text in a `<span>` tag and change your CSS selector to target the span:

```
function Reflection() {
    return (
        <div>
            Entry Page
            <form class="reflectionForm">
                <label for="newEntryId">
                    <span>New Entry:</span>
                    <textarea type="text" id="newEntryId" name="newEntryName" rows="30" cols="75"/>
                </label>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```css
.reflectionForm label span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: green
}
```

Live Demo:

```css
.reflectionForm label span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: green
}
```

```html
<div> Entry Page
  <form class="reflectionForm">
    <label for="newEntryId">
      <span>New Entry:</span>
      <textarea type="text" id="newEntryId" name="newEntryName" rows="30" cols="75"></textarea>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I searched and could not find anything that would help. Moving forward, I'll be more aware of what I'm specifically targeting when styling with CSS.